# how to use the <base> tag in services page in php website

Tags: php, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<base href="http://localhost/drreddys/" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dr Reddy's | Services</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;background-color:  cadetblue;}
  .a_heading{width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#ebebeb;}
.a_title{width: 100%;color: #603090;height: 50px;text-align: center;box-shadow: 5px 2px;}
#your-div {
    background: url("../images/about5.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: border-box;
    height: 400px;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include_once '../admin/header.php';?>
 <div class="a_heading" style="margin-top: 200px;">
       <h1 class="a_title" style="margin-top: 200px;">Services</h1>
     </div>
    <div id="your-div"></div>
<div id="tabs" style='margin-top: 100px; margin-left: 150px; '>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Primary Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Kidney Diseases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Dialysis Procedures</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-4">Annual Physicals</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-5">Adult Immunizations</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#tabs-6">Preventive Health Care</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-7">Pre-operative Clearance</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Primary Care</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Kidney Diseases</h2>
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Dialysis Procedures</h2>
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-4" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Annual Physicals</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-5" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Adult Immunizations</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-6" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Preventive Health Care</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
    <div id="tabs-7" style="border-radius: 25px;">
    <h2 style="color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;">Pre-operative Clearance</h2>
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Pha`enter code here`sellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
       </div>
      </div>

     </body>
  </html>
```

Well, i have issues in using the  html tag in my website.
Mine is a dynamic website and this tag works on all pages except the `services.php` page
if i include the base tag as `<base href="http://localhost/drreddys/"/>` 
the whole services page  gets disturbed.
Can you please help in resolving this issue

my header.php

```
<!--

 <style> 

@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(css/Evolution_True_Type_Font_by_PAULW.ttf);
}

div #logo {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    font-size: 48px;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

#container {
    border: 0px solid;
    max-width: 640px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.post {
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Core variables and mixins*/
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="../css/grid.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../css/animate.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../css/camera.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href="../css/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<script src="../js/camera.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
    <div id="stuck_container">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <div class="brand put-left" style="padding-top: 40px;">
        <div id="logo">Dr Reddy's</div>

                    </div>

                    <nav class="nav put-right">
                        <ul class="sf-menu">
                            <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">About</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dolor sit amet</a>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ctetur adipisicing</a>
                                    <li><a href="#">Elit sed do</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Iusmod tempor</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Incididunt ut labore</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Et dolore magna</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Aliqua Ut enim</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Minim veniam</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

       -->
       <style>

a {

    color:  #232222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;

}

a:hover {

    color: #fff;

}

img {

    width: 100%;

}

header {

    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #4C9CF1;
    z-index: 100;

}
#logo{
     margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
/*    background: url(images/logo.png) no-repeat center;*/
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
vertical-align:  central;
}

nav {

/*    float: right;*/
    padding: 20px;    

}

#menu-icon {

    display: hidden;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
   /* background: #4C8FEC url(images/menu-icon.png) center;*/

}

a:hover#menu-icon {

    background-color: #444;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;

}

ul {

    list-style: none;

}

li {

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px

}

.current {

    color: #2262AD;

}

section {

    margin: 80px auto 40px;
    max-width: 980px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px

}
/*MEDIA QUERY*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) { /*If device width is higher than 640px use this css and if less than 640px use above */

    header {

        position: absolute;

    }

    #menu-icon {

        display:inline-block;

    }

    nav ul, nav:active ul { 

        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 5px solid #444;
        right: 20px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;

    }

    nav li {

        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;

    }

    nav:hover ul {

        display: block;

    }
}


       </style>
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

<head>
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1">-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
 @font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
/*    src: url(css/cardigan_titling_bd.otf);*/
 src: url(css/Oswald-Light.otf);
}

 #logo {
/*     margin-top: 20px;*/
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}  
.menu{
    background-color: orange;
/*    opacity: 0.5;*/
    filter: Alpha(opacity = 50); /* IE8 and earlier */
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    padding-right: 25px;
/*    margin-top: -25px;*/
}

  .custom #fixed-social-icons { background:transparent; width:32px; height:32px;position:fixed; top:50px; left:0px; }
 .custom #fixed-social-icons a { display:block; height:32px; width:32px; }
  .custom #fixed-social-icons a.social-twitter { background: url("images/twitter.jpg") 32px 32px no-repeat; }
  custom #fixed-social-icons a.social-rss { background: url("images/google_plus.jpg") 32px 32px no-repeat; }
  .custom #fixed-social-icons a.social-linkedin { background: url("images/linked_in.jpg") 32px 32px no-repeat;}
  .custom #fixed-social-icons a.social-facebook { background: url("images/facebook.jpg") 32px 32px no-repeat; }
.custom #social-icons a img { float:left; height: 20px;width: 20px; }
#icons{
position: fixed;
top:300px;
left: 0px;

margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width:50px;
height:300px; 
z-index:999999;
}
</style>


</head>
<!--<body>-->

<header>

    <div id=logo>Dr. Samathha R Reddy, M.D. </br>
    Personalized Medicine </br>
    <span style="float:right;margin-right: 200px;">Call Us on 6199007302 </span> 
        <?php
function add_my_social_icons() {
///if (is_page()) { ?>
  <div id="icons">
  <a href="https://twitter.com/YOUR_USER_NAME"><img src="images/twitter.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="Twitter" /></a>
  <a href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/YOUR_FEED_URL"><img src="images/google_plus.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="RSS" /></a>
  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME"><img src="images/linked_in.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/YOUR_FB_IDENTIFIER"><img src="images/facebook.jpg" width="32" height="32" alt="Facebook" /></a>
  </div>
<?php // }
}
add_my_social_icons();?>
</div>

     <div class="menu" style="border-radius: 25px;">
        <nav>
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul style="font-family: myFirstFont; font-size: 25px;">
                <li><a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="cms/about_us.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="cms/services.php">Services</a></li>

                <li><a href="book_app.php">Appointment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Payment</a></li>
                <li><a href="cms/contact_us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="cms/feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </div>

    </header>
<!--</body>-->
<!--</html>-->
```

Comment: Post your code, other wise you will not get a proper answer

Comment: okay i will post code

Comment: i include base tag in <head></head>. is that okay

Comment: Include your base tag in your code, and then tell me what the error is

Comment: okay i will do that.

Comment: i have added the base tag.

Comment: then the home page gets included in this services.php   page

Comment: After adding base tag what is the error on which page it will redirect?

Comment: the page is not redirected, but the home page gets displayed along with services.php page

Comment: Well in that case some thing from `services.php` page is causing error. I assume if there is a base tag included, that may be causing trouble.

Comment: what to do for that? i even removed the jquery files and checked whether they conflict, but that is not the case

Comment: try commenting the portion where you are including the services.php file and then run the script

Comment: i did not understand ....................

Comment: Remove this line `<?php include_once '../admin/header.php';?> ` and then run your code

Comment: i removed the line and it displays the sevices.php page without header without any disturbances. But then how to include the header.php

Comment: what is the name of your current page?

Comment: http://localhost/drreddys/cms/servces.php  and header page url is http://localhost/drreddys/admin/header.php

Comment: Edit your question and post header.php too

Comment: 1st and foremost remove the commented code, 2nd try adding the base tag in header.php and dont add it in the services.php i assume rest will be fine. And put this `<?php include_once '../admin/header.php';?>` back in services.php

Comment: well , i still get the same error...   the index page still displays on the services.php page

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have not added the base tag in header please add following code in your header

```
<base href="[DOMAIN]" >
```

Comment: But i cant see the base tag in your given html code.